# LINQ query WHERE SUM is greater than a number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a series of shelves in a warehouse mapped in a database. The shelves themselves contain boxes that are measured by size in cubic feet. I want to perform a query and filter out the locations that have a minimum amount of cubic feet free in their shelves. I am able to run the query that shows the amount of free space, however the `WHERE` clause to limit the results of the `SUM` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here is my query to get all of the shelves with their free space and total space:

```
Dim shelves As IQueryable(Of Location) = _db.Locations.Include(Function(l) l.Boxes)
    .Select(Function(loc) New With 
    {
        .LocationID = loc.LocationID,
        .WarehouseID = loc.WarehouseID,
        .Warehouse = loc.Warehouse.Name,
        .Row = loc.Row, 
        .Column = loc.Column, 
        .Bunk = loc.Bunk,
        .TotalSpace = loc.Footage,
        .FreeSpace = (loc.Footage - loc.Boxes.Select(Function(s) s.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()) 
     }).ToList()
```

This returns the correct values for each location, including the correct amount of free space. When I introduce the `WHERE` clause, it has no effect. Here is my query with the `WHERE` clause included:

```
Dim shelves As IQueryable(Of Location) = _db.Locations.Include(Function(l) l.Boxes)
    .Where(Function(l) (l.Boxes.Select(Function(e) e.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() >= EmptySpace))
    .Select(Function(loc) New With 
    {
        .LocationID = loc.LocationID,
        .WarehouseID = loc.WarehouseID,
        .Warehouse = loc.Warehouse.Name,
        .Row = loc.Row, 
        .Column = loc.Column, 
        .Bunk = loc.Bunk,
        .TotalSpace = loc.Footage,
        .FreeSpace = (loc.Footage - loc.Boxes.Select(Function(s) s.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()) 
     }).ToList()
```

Since `.FreeSpace` returns the correct values I'm not sure why it can't filter by that same value in my `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

You original Where predicate

```
.Where(Function(l) (l.Boxes.Select(Function(e) e.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() >= EmptySpace))
```

was not calculating the free space, which is why it had no effect.

You will notice that in your initial select you calculated free space as

```
(loc.Footage - loc.Boxes.Select(Function(s) s.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum())
```

Notice `loc.Footage` was missing in the Where predicate.

That would mean that this updated query should work

```
Dim shelves As IQueryable(Of Location) = _db.Locations.Include(Function(l) l.Boxes)
    .Where(Function(loc) (loc.Footage - loc.Boxes.Select(Function(s) s.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()) >= EmptySpace)
    .Select(Function(loc) New With 
    {
        .LocationID = loc.LocationID,
        .WarehouseID = loc.WarehouseID,
        .Warehouse = loc.Warehouse.Name,
        .Row = loc.Row, 
        .Column = loc.Column, 
        .Bunk = loc.Bunk,
        .TotalSpace = loc.Footage,
        .FreeSpace = (loc.Footage - loc.Boxes.Select(Function(s) s.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()) 
     }).ToList()
```

---

### Original Answer

Try applying the filter on the projected objects after the select

```
Dim shelves As IQueryable(Of Location) = _db.Locations.Include(Function(l) l.Boxes)    
.Select(Function(loc) New With 
{
    .LocationID = loc.LocationID,
    .WarehouseID = loc.WarehouseID,
    .Warehouse = loc.Warehouse.Name,
    .Row = loc.Row, 
    .Column = loc.Column, 
    .Bunk = loc.Bunk,
    .TotalSpace = loc.Footage,
    .FreeSpace = (loc.Footage - loc.Boxes.Select(Function(s) s.Size).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()) 
 })
.Where(Function(loc) loc.FreeSpace >= EmptySpace)
.ToList()
```

That way the free space is already calculated and included in the anonymous object.

Comment: Thanks, this works. My procedure is part of a Web API controller that only returns 20 results at a time. This runs a lot slower than the query without the where clause, but that's understandable as it has to calculate the free space for the millions of cubic feet before it can return the results. Can you think of an way to improve performance?

Comment: @Nse I am only seeing your message now. Did you figure out where you made your mistake with the where clause? I think I just saw what was omitted from your where filter.